# Function literal with a receiver invocation

Tags: kotlin, dsl

I can't seem to find much documentation on why the second invocation of foo works. Using the receiver as an argument doesn't make sense to me. I realize it might be more of a use case for DSLs but for some reason I can't wrap my head around how it is even possible. Can someone break it down?

```
val foo: Int.() -> Int = {
    plus(1)
}

fun main() {

    val x = 1.foo()
    val y = foo(1)
}
```

Comment: The receiver is essentially just the first parameter of the function. [This documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance) claims using the `foo(1)` approach is actually "preferred", and also implies the ability to do `1.foo()` is only to offer syntax that aligns with extension functions.

Comment: Yeah I eventually came to this conclusion. The first invocation seems more visually appealing I guess but the second invocation is a more accurate depiction of what is actually happening.

Comment: I don't like the inconsistency with `fun Int.foo(): Int`. If `foo` was defined as a function, you couldn't call it using `foo(1)`. So why does it allow you to call it when defined as a val?

Comment: @k314159 Yeah, I find it weird, too. Especially since the receiver of an extension function is also effectively the first (or last?) parameter of the function. Or at least, that's how it works on the JVM (maybe it's different on other platforms?). I believe `foo(1)` should work either for both higher-order functions and extension functions, or neither. Which effectively means I believe it shouldn't work for either, as I assume allowing `foo(1)` for extension functions would make the compiler's job harder for basically no benefit.

Comment: I have created an [issue on Kotlin YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-64323/Inaccurate-documentation-description-Non-literal-values-of-function-types-with-and-without-a-receiver-are-interchangeable) related to the documentation about this.

Comment: @Slaw To be fair the documentation never said explicitly that the "no receiver approach" is preferred

Comment: @Thomas "_If the value has a receiver type, the receiver object **should** be passed as the first argument. Another way..._" -- That wording implies, to me, that passing the receiver as the first argument is the preferred approach, and that the "_another way_" is the "inferior" alternative. Granted, it's probably not that deep, but that's how I read the documentation.